# Upload large file in partial chunks to MySql database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am writing a website which allows a user to upload a pdf file to a MySql database using ASP.NET Webforms (company issued requirements). The problem I currently have is when the file gets too big (100MB+) it gives

> Failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Currently I am writing for it to break the file in chunks and upload it piece by piece, but I wanted to know if there might be an easier way or a built-in SQL Statement for this?

I have looked at the 'Web.config' file for a way to enable uploading in chunks but I haven't found anything that works by editing it.
I have also tried looking for solutions in editing the 'my.ini' file but haven't found anything that works yet.

tl;dr

Need a function to break a file into parts to upload to MySql server using ASP.Net WebForms

Comment: Are you storing document the bytes in the database? If you are, considering saving the file to disk on the server and save the file path and required meta data to the database

Comment: @Vince - Yes we are storing the document bytes within the database. Thank you for the suggestion I will try and see if it works.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a filestream : https://codingsight.com/storing-files-in-sql-database-using-filestream-part1/
or filetable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Vince Thank you, we decided to go with the save the file path and required meta data instead of the entire file